# Navigation menu with dropdown using Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, helper

Handlebars.js seems to be a good solution but I'm having an issue trying to add a sample model to some markup.

I am trying to create a top level navigation with a dropdown and am having issues with a nested `each` helper.

JSON file:

```
{
    "modifier": "",
    "decorator": "",
    "title": "Main Navigation",
    "main-nav-items": [
        {
            "nav-id": 0,
            "nav-link": "/en",
            "nav-text": "Home",
            "active": "class=\"active\""
        },
        {
            "nav-id": 1,
            "nav-link": "/en/about-launch-sitecore",
            "nav-text": "About Launch Sitecore",
            "dropdown": "class=\"dropdown\"",
            "dropdown-toggle": "class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\"",
            "dropdown-caret": "<b class=\"caret\"></b>"
        },
        {
            "nav-id": 2,
            "nav-link": "/en/team",
            "nav-text": "Team"
        },
        {
            "nav-id": 3,
            "nav-link": "/en/glossary",
            "nav-text": "Glossary"
        },
        {
            "nav-id": 4,
            "nav-link": "/en/contact-us",
            "nav-text": "Contact Us"
        }
    ],
    "sub-nav-items": [
        {
            "nav-id": 0,
            "nav-link": "/en/about-launch-sitecore/getting-started",
            "nav-text": "Getting Started"
        },
        {
            "nav-id": 1,
            "nav-link": "/en/about-launch-sitecore/our-strategy",
            "nav-text": "Our Strategy"
        },
        {
            "nav-id": 2,
            "nav-link": "/en/about-launch-sitecore/building-the-site",
            "nav-text": "Building the Site"
        },
        {
            "nav-id": 3,
            "nav-link": "/en/about-launch-sitecore/optimizing-the-experience",
            "nav-text": "Optimizing the Experience"
        },
        {
            "nav-id": 4,
            "nav-link": "/en/about-launch-sitecore/sitecore-8",
            "nav-text": "Sitecore 8"
        }
    ]
}
```

HTML code (using Bootstrap 2.3.2):

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            {{#each main-nav-items}}
            <li id="ctl05_rptDropDownMenu_MenuLi_{{nav-id}}"{{#if active}} {{{active}}}{{/if}}{{#if dropdown}} {{{dropdown}}}{{/if}}>
                <a id="ctl05_rptDropDownMenu_MenuLink_{{nav-id}}"{{#if dropdown-toggle}} {{{dropdown-toggle}}}{{/if}} href="{{nav-link}}">{{nav-text}}{{#if dropdown-caret}} {{{dropdown-caret}}}{{/if}}</a>
                {{#if dropdown}}
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              {{#sub-nav-items}}
                    <li id="ctl05_rptDropDownMenu_ctl00_1_MenuLi_{{nav-id}}">
                        <a id="ctl05_rptDropDownMenu_ctl00_1_MenuLink_{{nav-id}}" href="{{nav-link}}">{{nav-text}}</a>
                    </li>
              {{/sub-nav-items}}
            </ul>
                {{/if}}
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </div>    
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot get `sub-nav-items` to render even though the nav with the dropdown has the correct conditional.

Client-side templating is still relatively new to me so any other formatting tips and best practices are also welcome in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be [on the homepage under Paths](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths) but it was not obvious. What I need to do is to add a lookup path on `sub-nav items` so that it searches for `sub-nav-items` out of the current array:

```
{{#each ../sub-nav-items}}
    <li id="ctl05_rptDropDownMenu_ctl00_1_MenuLi_{{nav-id}}">
       <a id="ctl05_rptDropDownMenu_ctl00_1_MenuLink_{{nav-id}}" href="{{nav-link}}">{{nav-text}}</a>
    </li>
{{/sub-nav-items}}
```

The reason to do this is because the `each` look only searches for expressions within the current array item. It finds the dropdown unordered list element just fine but cannot find `sub-nav-items` because it doesn't exist within the iterated array item. `sub-nav-items` exists at a layer above the iterated item. Handlebars thinks sub-nav-items exists as a node inside the array item.

As a noob to Handlebars and higher level programming, this was not obvious to me so I did not understand why it wouldn't locate `sub-nav-items`.